# Woo-commerce: Adding additional page sections using a child theme

Tags: plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm hoping to modify Woo-commerce by adding a section to every product page. I have a child theme setup with a copy of the Woo-commerce template files in it. I want the new section to appear under the product description section. The problem is I'm unsure how I can do this.

Product Description appears as description.php in the 'tabs' folder, does anybody know where is this page loaded from though? Am I correct in thinking that I can add a new file 'newSection.php' in tabs. And then call it after 'description.php'?

Comment: I posted an answer, then realised I wasn't quite sure what you were asking. Do you want to add a new tab, or just modify the content of the description tab?

Comment: I'm hoping to add a new section under neath the product description, the  new will section will sit under the the product description tab. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to modify the description tab, then modify the tab template in your child theme at `woocommerce/single-product/tabs/description.php` to meet your needs.